Terraform iteration with for_each and a list
I'm creating a Azure API management products and product APIs with terraform below. This will work fine with only one product. Once I try to use a list it doesn't work.  I think I need to do a for loop to re-run the same code on the other object in the list.
resource "azurerm_api_management_product" "products" {
  count = length(var.create_product_groups)
  api_management_name   = azurerm_api_management.api-mgmt-service.name
  display_name          = var.create_product_groups[count.index]
  product_id            = var.create_product_groups[count.index]
  published             = true
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_api_management.api-mgmt-service.resource_group_name
  subscription_required = true

  # Optional Arguments
  approval_required   = true
  description         = ""
  subscriptions_limit = 1
  terms               = ""
}
resource "azurerm_api_management_product_api" "products" {
  for_each = var.apis
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.api-mgmt-service.name
  api_name            = each.value.name
  product_id          = each.value.products
  resource_group_name = azurerm_api_management.api-mgmt-service.resource_group_name

variable "apis" {
  type = map(object({
    name          = string
    revision      = string
    path          = string
    k8s_backend   = string
    content_value = string
    products = list(string)
  }))
}

  apis = {
    api1 = {
      name          = "api1"
      revision      = "1"
      path          = "pathapi"
      content_value = file("./files/api.yaml")
      k8s_backend   = "https://xyz.cloud"
      products = ["product1,product2"]
    }


Can you brief the requirement on product list. @Matt Bernard

Please include in your question the exact error you are getting, or if no error, a description of the current behavior, and the expected behavior.

@Jahnavi All products will be the have the same requirements so its really just a name change.
@MarkB then is when I change to a list with 1 or more elements.

each.value.products is list of string with 1 element

Inappropriate value for attribute "product_id": string required.
``

I also received the same error when I tried in my environment. Checking on it and update you shortly. @MattBernard

What does create_product_groups variable contains? @MattBernard

Just a simple list of 1 or more product groups to create.  ie ["product_group1","product_group2"]
My idea to is match the create_product_groups values to the products under api1.

So, correct me if my understanding is wrong. Are the create_product_groups variable and Api products contain same values or different? @MattBernard

The same @Jahnavi

Updated the solution below. Please check. @MattBernard

To achieve your requirement, merge function would be useful as:

It takes an arbitrary number of maps or objects and returns a single map or object that contains a merged set of elements from all arguments.

Refer here for the usage of merge function in terraform.
Below is the complete terraform code to meet your requirement:
main.tf:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.0.1"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
subscription_id = "xxxx"
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Jahnavi"
}
 
data "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apimjah"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_product" "products" {
  count = length(var.create_product_groups)
  api_management_name   = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  display_name          = var.create_product_groups[count.index]
  product_id            = var.create_product_groups[count.index]
  published             = true
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_api_management.example.resource_group_name
  subscription_required = true  
}
locals {
  merge_func = merge([
    for key, apival in var.apis:
      {
        for product in apival.products:
          "${key}-${product}" => {
            name          = apival.name
            product       = product
          }
      }
  ]...)
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_product_api" "product_apis" {
  for_each = local.merge_func
 
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  api_name            = each.value.name
  product_id          = each.value.product
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_api_management_product.products
  ]
}

var.tf:
variable "apis" {
  type = map(object({
    name          = string
    revision      = string
    k8s_backend   = string
    products = list(string)
  }))
 default = {
 api1 = {
      name          = "newapi"
      revision      = "1"
      k8s_backend   = "https://xyz.cloud"
      products = ["product3","product4"]
    }
}
}
variable "create_product_groups" {
type = list(string)
default = ["product3","product4"]
}

Output:




